# Lazy class parameter setting

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree

I am attempting to create a tree structure in javascript. Here is the node class:

```
class NodeTree {
constructor(parent, chkAttacked, chkType, coords) {
    var children; 
    this.parent = parent;
    this.chkAttacked = chkAttacked;
    this.chkType = chkType;
    this.coords = coords;
}

setChild(node) {
    children.push(node);
}

getCoords() {
    return coords; 
}

getParent() { 
    return parent;
}

getChildren() { 
    return children;
}

getChkAttacked() { 
    return chkAttacked;
}

getChkType() {
    return chkType;
}
}
```

The child Nodes don't get declared at the same time as the object is created and for that reason are set later on. As it stands i get a "not defined error". How do I set child nodes outside of a constructor?

Comment: it seems you forgot to write `this` before using instance variables.

Comment: @Ruslan `this` for `children` or `this` for `node` ?

Comment: `children` and all the variables inside getters. It should be `return this.coords` instead of `return coords`

Comment: `this.children.push(node)`

Comment: The same thing in the constructor `this.children = []`